# Google Sheets - How can i Sum overlapping cells from several different imported named ranges?

Tags: sum, google-sheets-formula, overlapping

Im facing a bottleneck guys, hopefully someone can help me out to solve this.

Im working in Google Shets and have several named ranges i want to import in a single sheet, from several different files. So, what im using to import a single range is =importrange("sheeturl","namedrange")

What im struggling with is importing the other ranges like this and have all overlapping cells sum. See a simplified example of what im looking for in the image, below:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhcfO.png)

i tried formulas like =sum(importrange("sheeturl1","namedrange1"),importrange("sheeturl2","namedrange2")) but this only summed all the values in a signle cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=arrayformula(
              importrange("Sheet_ID","NamedRange1")+
              importrange("Sheet_ID","NamedRange2")
              )
```